# Defining pure virtual functions from inherited virtual base classes

Tags: c++, inheritance

Suppose I have a class with a virtual method and two derived classes that define that method in different ways:

```
class animal
{
    virtual bool isBlack() = 0;
};

class blackAnimal : public animal
{
    virtual bool isBlack() { return true; }
};

class stripedAnimal : public animal
{
    virtual bool isBlack() { return false; }
};
```

Now I want to derive another class form the virtual base class, and make two new subtypes:

```
class bigCat : public animal {}; // isBlack() is still pure virtual

// I wish that this worked and that isBlack would return true
class jaguar : public bigCat, public blackAnimal {};

// I wish that this worked and that isBlack would return false
class tiger : public bigCat, public stripedAnimal {};
```

How can I do this. When I do this, the isBlack() method of animal stays virtual. I'd like that when I derive from a class that defines animal::isBlack(), that isBlack becomes a working virtual function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a "working" implementation, but I would strongly recommend not doing this:

```
class Animal {
    public:
        virtual bool isBlack() = 0;
}

class BlackAnimal : public virtual Animal {
    public:
        virtual bool isBlack() {return true;}
}

class BigCat : public virtual Animal {}

class Jaguar : public BigCat, public BlackAnimal { }
```

You might want to read https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/multiple-inheritance for an overview of multiple inheritance in C++ and this section in particular https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/multiple-inheritance#mi-diamond about virtual inheritance.

Broadly the problem here is your jaguar class has two isBlack() functions - the one from animal, and the one from blackAnimal. Using virtual inheritance results in only one instance of the 'animal' base class, with blackAnimal's isBlack() taking priority if you set it up right.

(I assume that you wanted isBlack() to be virtual and made a mistake in writing out your example, and also that you're aware that classes that have virtual functions should have virtual destructors).

Comment: yes, that first method is meant to be virtual. And I'm aware that I'd need a virtual destructor, but I wanted to keep the example simple.

Comment: Your example doesn't quite work for me, since you factored out bigCat. The idea is that the "bigCat" class in this case would do some stuff that depends on methods of animal. And then the jaguar and tiger classes would specialize from there.

Comment: That was for simplification purposes - it works with the bigCat class present as well. I'll edit it in.